# Symfony - How can I insert behaviors in my doctrine migrations?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, migration, behavior

Is it possible to add behaviors (eg. actAs Timestampable) in a doctrine migration to avoid defining the created_at and updated_at columns ?

Thank's in advance !

Comment: The solution here :

http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/5957eb2ad2dcb407

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no way to add behaviors in the migration code.

BUT! if you are using doctrine 1.1 (it's easy to migrate from 1.0) you can instead modify your schema, add the behavior, and let doctrine generate the migration code as explained here:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/new-to-migrations-in-1-1

Answer (score 0):

FYI

http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/5957eb2ad2dcb407#